# Create multiple canvases in a loop, only last function gets called

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, html5-canvas

The code below creates multiple canvases with relative input boxes.

The problem is that after running the code only last canvas and its input box are working.

```js
var art = function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var inpbx = document.createElement('input');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.getElementById("bx").appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(inpbx);
    div.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.style = "border:1px solid gray; height:100px";
    var updateCanvas = function() {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
      ctx.font = "30px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(inpbx.value, 10, 50);
    };
    inpbx.addEventListener("change", updateCanvas, false);
  }
};
```

```html
<button onClick="art()">Do some</button>
<div id="bx"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because all functions you create point to the same variable `i`. Which in the end equals `4`. To avoid it you may wrap loop body in a function:

```
var art = function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    (function (i) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      var inpbx = document.createElement('input');
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

      document.getElementById('bx').appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(inpbx);
      div.appendChild(canvas);

      canvas.style = 'border:1px solid gray; height:100px';

      var updateCanvas = function() {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        ctx.font = '30px Arial';
        ctx.fillText(inpbx.value, 10, 50);
      };

      inpbx.addEventListener('change', updateCanvas, false);
    })(i)
  }
};
```

In ES6 you can just change `var i = 1` to `let var i = 1`.

Comment: Thank you Danil for quick responce